# Shared Folder Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to store shared folders on linux(guest) but view on Windows(host.)

There are numerous reasons I would prefer this set up.  Namely file permissions should be kept correct on linux compared to if the files are store on Windows.

Is there a way to do this reverse share on the virtual machine?

Comment: Don't virtualbox shard folders work by keeping a copy on the guest *and* on the host? When you shutdown the guest / virtualbox the shared files are still there (on the host), if you delete the host files then run the guest again, are they gone or still there?

Comment: @Xen2050 they are gone.  Maybe this functionality has changed in newer versions but shared folders in virtual box are basically network folders but called something different.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't too sure on the details. Could try storing the files in another folder on the guest/linux, and link them into the shared folder... guess I'll make that an answer

Comment: @Xen2050 then how do I access the files in Windows?

Comment: Through the link & through the shared folder

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the files in another (not shared) folder on the guest/linux, and link them into the shared folder. Symbolic links might work, but hard links definitely should.

That way, the files & their attributes stay on linux, but should still be readable through the links shared to the host/windows.

According to an answer to [How to make Guest OS follow symlinks from shared folder](https://askubuntu.com/a/446328/129271) on askubuntu, you need to do this first

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

and then [fully restart VirtualBox with admin right](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:29), other Windows 7 users reports it works. (There's lots of discussion on that comments thread, about Windows as well, in case the specific option has been changed now, digging through the source code might be required to find the new one).

---

Another idea - have Windows save the linux file permissions, using the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/), though WSL might only be available for Windows 10 ([Install Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)) & Windows Server.

WSL was designed to support the full fidelity of Linux file systems, and 
allow interoperability with drives and files in Windows, so shouldn't have any problems with linux file attributes.

---

Another idea, you could keep a shell script to "fix" the file permissions/owners (with a few `chmod` / `chown` lines) so they're ready to use in linux, after reading them from Windows.

Or, store/share them in a tar archive in the shared folder.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately error "Invalid  cross-device link"  Try both hard & soft.

Comment: Where does the error come from? Creating the link in linux, or virtualbox?

Comment: Linux not virtualbox.

Comment: Aren't the shared folder and the files you're trying to link on the same filesystem? Usually Virtualbox puts the shard folder in the user's home, so they're on the same filesystem so linking them should work. If the files are on different filesystems, move one of them to the other - everything in home is probably easiest

Comment: No.  There is zero ways I can imagine having access on both operating and having the link work correctly.

Comment: Edited to show how to make it work (you can search for answers yourself too ;-)

Comment: I'll add a link to the rather long comments on virtualbox.org, apparently restarting virtualbox the correct way is required, but other users on Windows 7 report it works, eventually

Comment: I believe the symlinks are going to be based off of the machine which is hosting the files, which I will believe means I will not be able to use symlink linking to a guest file/folder.

Comment: Things may have changed now, but at least the one fellow ([comment:29 by abiliofaria](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:29) said it was working for Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12 guest. Anyway, I've got another idea about having Windows save the right permissions, I'll edit it in

Comment: Wsl as you know doesn't work with windows 7 and has substantial speed issues to recommend using it in addition to a virtual machine.